# Existence of countable dense normal subgroups of global Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups

Let $K$ be a number field, $S$ a finite set of primes of $K$ and $ G_{K,S} $ the Galois group of the maximal extension of $ K $ (inside a fixed algebraic closure of $K$) unramified outside $ S $. In Theorem 10.2.5 of [Cohomology of Number Fields](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-37889-1), it's proved that the group $ G_{K,S} $ is topologically generated by the conjugacy classes of finitely many elements, and hence $ G_{K,S} $ contains a proper dense normal subgroup if $ G_{K,S} $ is infinite. Note that if $ G_{K,S} $ is topologically finitely generated, then $G_{K,S}$ contains a countable dense subgroup.

> **Question:** Is it true that the profinite group $ G_{K,S} $ contains a countable dense normal subgroup, at least at the level of conjecture?

I know that it's still an open problem whether $ G_{K,S} $ is topologically finitely generated. Any comments and reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes: a metrizable compact space is indeed separable.

Comment: @YCor Do you mean that any metrizable profinite group (=first countable profinite group) contains a countable dense normal subgroup? Maybe you missed the condition “NORMAL"? This conclusion shocks me, could you point out some references or say a few more words?

Comment: Do you know any examples of infinite nonabelian topologically finitely generated profinite groups that have a countable dense normal subgroup? I find it unlikely that these things even exist at all — for instance, I don't have a candidate inside $\hat F_2$ (surely $F_2 \subseteq \hat F_2$ is not normal, is it??).

Comment: I indeed missed the word "normal", sorry.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn certainly you also want to discard those with an open abelian subgroup.

Comment: When $G $ is semisimple ($G $ is the Cartesian product of infinitely many finite simple groups, and the restricted direct product is a countable dense normal subgroup).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn no, there's non for $\hat{F}_2$. The reason is that the largest 2-step nilpotent pro-$p$-quotient (for some chosen prime $p$) also has no dense countable normal subgroup. Indeed, this is the Heisenberg group over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, and in this group, the union of countable conjugacy classes is not dense (and is reduced to the center).

Comment: For the question, I think it is enough to find a suitable infinite quotient with no such normal subgroup, and any $p$-adic analytic group with no abelian open subgroup should do the job. For instance, if there exists a local field of char. zero and a representation $G\to\mathrm{GL}_2(L)$ with open image, then we should be done. Whether there exists such a representation is maybe well-known to number theorists, but not to me.

Comment: You're right, e.g. Serre's Open Image Theorem guarantees the existence of such a representation.  So the answer to the question is no.